# How to get all the sum of the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a table named as **NOV_23** and I want to get the sum of the rightmost part and the sum for the Transportation, Meal, Lodging, Others, VAT, and Postage

```
CREATE TABLE NOV_23
(
EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
DIVISION VARCHAR (25),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR (25),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (25),
TRANSPORTATION INT,
LODGING INT,
TOTAL INT
);
```

Then i inserted some values

```
INSERT INTO NOV_23 VALUES             
('1','DivA','LName1','FName1','1','1','')

INSERT INTO NOV_23 VALUES
('2','DivA','LName2','FName2','5','5','')
```

Hence i get the result as:

```
  Employee_ID   Division Last_Name First_Name   Transportation   LODGING   TOTAL
  1             DivA     LNameA    FNameA       1                1       
  2             DivA     LNameB    FNameB       5                5
```

I can get the total by means of using the update

```
  UPDATE NOV_23
  SET TOTAL = (Transportation + Lodging)
  WHERE Employee_ID = 1
```

and

```
  UPDATE NOV_23
  SET TOTAL = (Transportation + Lodging)
  WHERE Employee_ID = 2
```

in which i can get the result as

```
  Employee_ID   Division Last_Name First_Name   Transportation   LODGING         TOTAL
  1             DivA     LNameA    FNameA       1                1          2
  2             DivA     LNameB    FNameB       5                5         10
```

What i want to know is how to get and display the sum of transportation (**6**), sum of lodging (**6**) and their overall summation which is (6+6 = **12**)

```
    Employee_ID   Division Last_Name First_Name   Transportation   LODGING        TOTAL
  1             DivA     LNameA    FNameA       1                1          2
  2             DivA     LNameB    FNameB       5                5         10
  --            --       --        --           6                6         12
```

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with both [tag:mysql] and [tag:oracle]. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate subtotals & cumulatives by using `rollup`

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name Name,
       SUM(Transportation) AS Transportation,
       SUM(Lodging) AS Lodging,
       SUM(Total) AS Total
  FROM nov_23
 GROUP BY ROLLUP (Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name)
 ORDER BY Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name;
```

You can calculate subtotals & cumulatives for all combinations of the dimensions specified by using `cube`

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name Name,
       SUM(Transportation) AS Transportation,
       SUM(Lodging) AS Lodging,
       SUM(Total) AS Total
  FROM nov_23
 GROUP BY CUBE (Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name)
 ORDER BY Employee_ID, Division, First_Name||' '||Last_Name;
```